# Feathers Starling AS3 AIR theme

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am building an AS3 project and I want to incorporate Feathers into it however I am confused when trying to follow their documentation. Probably my fault!

I am trying to add a theme (MinimalMobileTheme) however I have no idea where to add the theme folder or what folders I should be adding or how I show be adding them.

I am using Flash Builder.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ah okay I can't find the theme you're referencing but looking at another one I can see that there's a source directory and an assets directory.  It appears you would incorporate this with the feathers source code to compile the library, but I'll give it a shot and post as an answer if it works out.

Comment: The MinimalMobileTheme is part of the example package thats available but I still don't understand how to incorporate this into my app. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay just followed this tutorial to get Starling and Feathers setup:

http://gamua.com/starling/first-steps/

Downloaded each from their respective github repos and extracted then added the source folders to the build path as specified.  Change the renderMode to direct in the -app.xml file, and used the sample to be sure Starling itself is working fine.

I'm now working through the theme usage but it appears there's basically just one big sprite sheet png that's used and an XML file that goes along with it and a font for each theme.  I imagine this will work the same way where you simply download the source and link it in the flash builder project properties (can right click the project in the navigator and go to properties, or go to the main project menu and select properties, then go to ActionScript Build Path and add source folders).

The Embed's should be relative to one of your build paths.

Here's some resources that have helped me out so far:

http://wiki.starling-framework.org/feathers/getting-started

http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/starting-with-starling-ep-1-intro-setup/

Hang up I just ran into an error trying to use feathers and looks like the dev is aware and they're working through some kinks with current revisions so it'll take some considerable effort to dig through and fix the issue (being a newb here).  If you've gotten the current head of both to work or some older revision let me know and I'll take another crack at it.

http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/error-supportscissorrectangle-this_scissorrect

The example posted to the Feathers site uses this in the source:

```
private function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
{
    this._theme = new MetalWorksMobileTheme(this.stage); //start using theme

    this._navigator = new ScreenNavigator(); //components added afterwards have theme applied
    this.addChild(this._navigator);
```

Comment: Hey, I have the app setup i.e. starling, build paths etc and I have added a Feathers button to the display list but the theme is not showing. I was able to use the sprite sheet and XML to style the button but according to the documentation there is a way to include the theme and this applies the theme to all display objects. Including the theme is the issue I am having. Thanks again for looking

Comment: Hey just saw the comment too... would be interested in how to get past this issue, just happens when I try to use a button, according to their docs on themes it appears you have to just setup the theme before you make the feathers UI components (also be sure you're using the feathers ones not the flash.display or starling ones).

Comment: I managed to get past the scissor error by using the latest starling and feathers from Github. I have tried everything from including the theme folder in the build path, including the assets folder in the source and then the .as file in the build path etc. I have managed to import the theme successfully but still no theme. Looks like suing the sprite sheet which is a shame as it adds that extra level of difficulty.

Comment: Got as far as the source but unsure where/how to include the theme folder into the project.

Comment: OK I have managed to successfully import and there is one error: type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ImageLoader

Comment: If anyone wants to know you need to include the theme directory into the feathers package. Then include the assets directory into the root of the project. Doing this fixes all previous errors but ImageLoader is now the issue.

Answer (score 0):

follow the following steps
1)extract the file  feathers-1.0.1 to desktop
2)right click on the project name on your package explorer and go to properties
3)select source path
4)add new folder feathers-1.0.1\themes\MetalWorksMobileTheme\source folder on your desktop
5)ok. ok.
 then import package with

```
import feathers.themes.MetalWorksMobileTheme;
```

and follow the next steps in tutorial http://wiki.starling-framework.org/feathers/getting-started